# Convert lists to a diagonal matrix DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get returned a list of tuples in this format:

```
[date1, date2, date3]
[ticker1, ticker2, ticker3]
[value1, value2, value3]
```

I want to convert it into a pandas dataframe where the index are the dates, columns are the tickers and the data are the values.

Comment: Can you show us (visually) what you want as the desired output?

Comment: What you have shown here isn't a list of tuples. It's three separate lists. Can you be a bit more specific about the data you are working with?

Comment: That's not a list of tuples, that's a list of lists (or so you've given us to believe).

Answer (score 3):

Using `pivot`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(lst).T
df.pivot(*df)

1     ticker1 ticker2 ticker3
0                            
date1  value1    None    None
date2    None  value2    None
date3    None    None  value3
```

Comment: I like the idea of unpacking, super succinct.

Comment: `(lambda d: d.pivot(*d))(pd.DataFrame(lst).T)` OR `pd.DataFrame(lst).T.pipe(lambda d: d.pivot(*d))`

Answer (score 2):

### `Series` and `unstack`

```
lst = [['date1', 'date2', 'date3'],
       ['ticker1', 'ticker2', 'ticker3'],
       ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']]

pd.Series(lst[-1], lst[:2]).unstack()

      ticker1 ticker2 ticker3
date1  value1    None    None
date2    None  value2    None
date3    None    None  value3
```

---

### `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['date1', 'date2', 'date3'],
       ['ticker1', 'ticker2', 'ticker3'],
       ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']]

dd = defaultdict(dict)

for d, t, v in zip(*lst):
    dd[t][d] = v

pd.DataFrame(dd)

      ticker1 ticker2 ticker3
date1  value1    None    None
date2    None  value2    None
date3    None    None  value3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
values = [(1, 0, 1), (2, 9, 4), (3, 10, 4), (9, 22, 30)]

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(values)
print(data_frame)
```

I would need to see your specific code, because what you outlined appears to be a list of lists, not a list of tuples. But in theory, if you had a list of tuples, this is how you would create a DataFrame out of it. Here is your output:

```
   0   1   2
0  1   0   1
1  2   9   4
2  3  10   4
3  9  22  30
```

Comment: This is answering a different question, no?

Comment: @coldspeed No. if you have a different question you can ask though.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you understood. I think your answer is solving a different problem that OP didn't ask.